# Run button not reacting

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

When I press the run button it doesn't even prompt the AVD option screen.
I've tried:

- running through AVD manager- runs the AVD without my app.
- connecting my phone- still no prompt screen
- disabling ADB integration
- uninstalling and reinstalling android studio- I now have the most updated 
  versions of AS, SDK, Java
- AVD's with different API's and all  graphics options
- made sure I'm on app configuration

what else?
should I downgrade **AS version(3.0.1)**? to which?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve this way.

> Keyboard Shortcut: Shift+F10 -- Run the app

Or

**Edit Configuration for run**

[image]

Select appropirate module in module selection

[image]

Set Installation & launch option to default & select the target by the way you are using with device or emulator. If you select usb device/emulator it will run directly without prompting.

[image]

**UPDATED**

Check also default run configuration like below.

[image]

Comment: @Marg see updated answer. You got any error log or any message while clicking run button or button greyed out or something else. Try close & reopen the project & android studio as well after changing in configuration.

Comment: Button not grayed, and no error logs, just says gradle build finished. My default configurations are already set as you suggest .